# How to access remote filesystem on Windows CE device via command line

Tags: windows-ce

I can view files on my embedded Windows CE device via Windows CE Remote File Viewer, but would prefer to do it through the command line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since SO is for programmers the answer is following api's:

[CeFindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917424.aspx)
[CeFindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918923.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Somebody's done the hard work for you already. The xda project has a set of command line utilities that communicate over RAPI including:

pdir       - list wince directory

http://itsme.home.xs4all.nl/projects/xda/tools.html